# Move elements in array powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an array $jobs with elements as below

```
end time: 1312331233
host: vm1
name: \
C:\
start time: 13321232133
```

The output that I am after for $jobs[2] has spilt across into $jobs[3].
How can I get this array to look like:

```
end time: 1312331233
host: vm1
name: C:\
start time: 13321232133
```

Comment: Could you please share the code how you are splitting it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

converted the array to a list and whenever a "\" is matched in the element I replaced it with $array[3] and removed $array[3] from the list
Won't work if this is encountered across other elements but will do for now